# python string input to integer conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a script to ask a user to input a string containing round numbers separated by a space. Then I need to convert the string to integers.

Any pointers on where to start? This is what I've tried:

```
a=str(input('Voer een door spatie gescheiden lijst met getallen in:').split())
b=int(a)
print(b)
```

but I keep getting:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['50', '60']"
```

Comment: In Python3, `input` already produces a string, so `str(input(...))` is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to cast a string representation of a list, just split the contents into a list and use map to cast to ints:

```
inp = input('Voer een door spatie gescheiden lijst met getallen in:').split())
a,b = map(int,inp)
```

This presumes the user always enters two numbers separated by a space.

Safer use a while loop and a try/except:

```
while True:
    try:
        inp = input('Voer een door spatie gescheiden lijst met getallen in:').split()
        a, b  = map(int, inp)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
print(a,b)
```

If you have an unknown amount of ints entered:

```
  while True:
        try:
            inp = input('Voer een door spatie gescheiden lijst met getallen in:').split()
            nums = map(int, inp)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")
    for num in nums:
       print(num)
```

Using `python3`, map returns a map object so it is an efficient way to assign.
 `[int(x) for x in inp]` will also work but unless you need a list there is no point creating one.

Comment: @BhargavRao, there are two numbers entered, the OP needs to unpack the two and assign to variables then print.

Comment: @BhargavRao,  I presume the OP is using python3 so actually `map(int,inp)` is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

## The Lengthy Answer

Oversymplifyng the issue, the [`int` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) (follow the link to know the whole story) requires a single argument, either a numeric literal or a string.

Your code

```
>>> a=str(input('Voer een door spatie gescheiden lijst met getallen in: ').split())
```

is creating the textual representation of a list, because you use the `str` builtin that returns a textual representation of a python object:

```
>>> a
"['2', '3', '4', '5']"
```

The above is not the textual representation of a number, as required by `int`, but the textual representation of a list, so when you pass it to `int` it complains

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['2', '3', '4', '5']"
```

What if we omit the call to `str`?

```
>>> a = input('Voer een door spatie gescheiden lijst met getallen in: ').split()
>>> a
['2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> int(a)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Note that the error message is different: no more a `ValueError` but a `TypeError`.  We have a list, whose items are strings representing numbers, but we're not allowed to use the list *as is* as an argument to `int`.

Enter *list comprehension*, the contemporary idiom to manipulate the *contents* of a list (or of a generic *iterable*).

```
>>> [int(elt) for elt in a]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The syntax is easy, `[...]` you have the opening and closing bracket, as you would write when using a list literal, and inside you have an inside-out loop, first the body of the loop and then the `for` specification.  The results of the evaluation of the body are sequentially stored in a list, that the interpreter outputs for you, as you can see above we have no more strings representing numbers but integers. Assign the result of the list comprehension to a variable

```
>>> b = [int(elt) for elt in a]
```

and you're done:

```
>>> print(b)
[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: deserving long late answer ... Sad ... :(

Answer (score 0):

After `split` you have a `list` of `str`, so you need to convert each of the individual items to `int`.

You could use a list comprehension

```
b = [int(i) for i in a]
```

Or use `map`

```
b = list(map(int, a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert each element of the list into int using the following way,

`a = [int(each) for each in a]`

This will give you a list of integers that you could use in your program. In case if it is an invalid integer, then you can use `try-except`,

```
b = []
for each in a:
    try:
      b.append(int(each))
    except ValueError:
      print('Invalid number')
```